# Mobile menu on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mobile, menu

We are using Wordpress with the Avada 5.1.6 theme and Polylang plugin. 
The mobile menu does not show on the english version it shows on the portuguese version

I've inspected the generated html and the menu exists in both pages.

I tried disabling the Polylang plugin and the mobile menu does not show on any page

Thank you!

Comment: Care to explain why the -1 on this question?

Comment: [Lost my keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/185667), sorry...

Comment: Cool, glad you found them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:**
Don't forget to check the selected language before editing configurations that you need to share between languages!

**Long description**

The issue was that custom css was being applied to the english version of the website hiding the header.

The reason why the configuration for custom css was not considered initially was caused by the fact that Wordpress actually treats each language as their "own website", each one having different configurations, including custom css.

By selecting "all languages" on the Wordpress menu, it was possible to reset the custom css configuration for all languages at once.

Thanks.